# Select and display data as column header

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to select region wise data and want to show each region as column header.

My data:

```
region state   status
North   UP     invalid
North   HAR    invalid
North   MAH     valid
South   KER     valid
South   TAM     valid
South   KAR     valid
South   KAR     invalid
```

Output:

```
Status   North  south  total 
invalid   2      1      3
valid     1      3      4
total     3      4      7
```

How to do this?
This regions can be update later new region can be  added later

Is there any way to take all the active regions first then use this in the query
activeregions

Comment: I want to display the raw total as  well as colunm total

Answer (score 2):

```
select status,
       count(case when region = 'North' then 1 end) as North,
       count(case when region = 'South' then 1 end) as South
from tablename
group by status
```

Alternative solution, that can handle new regions later added:

```
select region, status, count(*)
from tablename
group by region, status
```

Another solution, that also can handle new regions later added:

```
select region,
       count(case when status = 'valid' then 1 end) as valid,
       count(case when status = 'invalid' then 1 end) as invalid
from tablename
group by region
```

Comment: how can i show when i am not sure about the region. may be my regions can increase later

Comment: So perhaps you should turn it the other way, one row/region, and columns for invalid and valid?

Comment: the alternative cases will not give the regions as colunm header

Comment: I know, use the first query if that's important to you. The alternatives are however more flexible to future changes.

Comment: count(case when region = activeregions then 1 end) as activeregions
        loo end
        from tablename group by status

Answer (score 0):

SQL is designed to get you records with a *before-known* number of columns. So you cannot get the data in the desired output format directly. There are two options mainly:

1) Select the aggregated data in rows:

```
select region, status, count(*)
from mytable
group by region, status
order by region, status;
```

Then let your app display the data in columns. (Loop and fetch data, build the columns in your GUI grid according to the data, i.e. add a new column in your grid each time you get a new region.)

2) Select distinct regions first, then select the data:

```
select distinct region
from mytable;
```

Now, that you got 'North' and 'South', let your app build the following query dynamically:

```
select status as "Status"
  , sum(case when region = 'North' then 1 else 0 end) as "North"
  , sum(case when region = 'South' then 1 else 0 end) as "South"
from mytable
group by status;
```

Comment: how to build the query dynamically

Comment: This depends on the language your app is written in. Something like: `foreach(region in regions) selectClause += ", sum(case when region = '" + region +"' then 1 else 0 end) as \"" + region + "\"";`

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1**
Please check [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cff1f/1)

```
FIRST STEP
```

Separately find out the count for active and inactive regions

```
    SELECT  'ACTIVE' "STATUS",NVL(REGION,'TOTAL') REGION,
         COUNT(REGION) REGCOUNT
  FROM TEMPPIVOTTEST
  where STATUS like 'ACTIVE'
  GROUP BY ROLLUP (REGION)
```

[image]

```
 SELECT  'INACTIVE' "STATUS",NVL(REGION,'TOTAL') REGION,
         COUNT(REGION) REGCOUNT
  FROM TEMPPIVOTTEST
   where STATUS like 'INACTIVE'
  GROUP BY ROLLUP (REGION)
```

[image]

In above queries we use GROUP By ROLLUP so the last row we will get the sum of all other rows

```
SECOND STEP
```

JOIN BOTH this queries 
AND use Pivot

```
     SELECT NVL(STATUS,'GRAND TOTAL') STATUS,SUM(EAST) EAST,SUM(NORTH) NORTH,SUM(SOUTH) SOUTH,SUM(TOTAL) TOTAL from  
      ( SELECT  'ACTIVE' "STATUS",NVL(REGION,'TOTAL') REGION,
         COUNT(REGION) REGCOUNT
  FROM TEMPPIVOTTEST
  where STATUS like 'ACTIVE'
  GROUP BY ROLLUP (REGION)
  union
  SELECT  'INACTIVE' "STATUS",NVL(REGION,'TOTAL') REGION,
         COUNT(REGION) REGCOUNT
  FROM TEMPPIVOTTEST
   where STATUS like 'INACTIVE'
  GROUP BY ROLLUP (REGION)
  )pivot (SUM(REGCOUNT) FOR (REGION) IN ('EAST' EAST,'NORTH' NORTH,'SOUTH' SOUTH,'TOTAL' TOTAL))
  GROUP BY ROLLUP (STATUS)
```

[image]

In pivot we need to give the regions which are present in table

**METHOD 2**  [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cff1f/4)

**Another way** for doing the same above query we have specified the status hard corded 'Active' and 'inactive' instead of that that we can use following query

```
   SELECT nvl(STATUS,'GRAND_TOTAL') STATUS,sum(EAST)EAST,sum(NORTH)NORTH,sum(SOUTH)SOUTH,sum(TOTAL) TOTAL from 
     (SELECT  STATUS,REGION,
         COUNT(REGION) REGCOUNT
  FROM TEMPPIVOTTEST
  GROUP BY  (STATUS,REGION)
  union
  SELECT  STATUS,'TOTAL'REGION,
         COUNT(REGION) REGCOUNT
  FROM TEMPPIVOTTEST
  GROUP BY (STATUS)

  )pivot (SUM(REGCOUNT) FOR (REGION) IN ('EAST' EAST,'NORTH' NORTH,'SOUTH' SOUTH,'TOTAL' Total))
  group by rollup (status)
```

oracle 10 g pivot will not work so we can make use of the case statement

```
select nvl(status,'total')status,SUM(NORTH) NORTH,SUM(SOUTH)SOUTH,SUM(EAST)EAST,sum(TOTAL)TOTAL from (select status,
   sum(case when region = 'NORTH' then 1 else 0 end) as "NORTH",
   sum(case when region = 'SOUTH' then 1 else 0 end) as "SOUTH",
   sum(case when region = 'EAST' then 1 else 0 end) as "EAST",
   sum(case when region  in('') then 0 else 1 end) as "TOTAL"
from  TEMPPIVOTTEST
group by status
)group by ROLLUP (STATUS)
```